# Why did Canonical choose to use the Qt toolkit for Ubuntu Touch and not Gtk?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-touch, gtk, qt, canonical

I recently came across a question on Quora:

> What are future plans for Gtk?
>   Is there plan for smartphone or tablet? Gnome focus on touch devices but Gtk software can not run on it?
>   On Quora, why Gtk topic only have 538 follower (Qt have 4k)?
>   I really worry about it :(

[Source](https://www.quora.com/Is-Gtk-dead)

This is an interesting question, and I considered answering it.
Unfortunately I have no idea why this is so...

So: **Why did Canonical choose to use the Qt toolkit for Ubuntu Touch and not Gtk?**

And why is it much less popular as a GUI toolkit?